# Can case is_numeric($action): be written another way?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if I can write is_numeric($action) someway like this:

```
switch ($action):
    case NULL:
...
```

`CASE INTEGER:` is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm not following.

Comment: If $action is an integer... any valid integer.

Comment: Why don't you just use `is_numeric()`?

Comment: Are you looking for [ctype_digit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)? It's more strict on what it considers a number.

Comment: I don't like to repeat mentioning $action. It sort of defeat the purpose of using switch statement instead of if statement.

Comment: is_numeric() returns true or false that's why Case integer will not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to do a type switch on an input value.

Theoretically you *cannot* use [`gettype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) due to the giant red warning:

> Never use `gettype()` to test for a certain type, since the returned
>   string may be subject to change in a future version. In addition, it
>   is slow too, as it involves string comparison.
>
> Instead, use the is_* functions.

Just between you and me, I expect it will work for at least a decade or so. But it makes you feel dirty, it's true.

In the quest for something officially supported, we might turn to this:

```
function get_type_stable($var) {
    $types = array('array','integer','double','string','object','resource','null');
    foreach($types as $type) {
        $typechecker = 'is_'.$type;
        if($typechecker($var)) {
            return $type;
        }
    }
}

switch(get_type_stable($var)) {
    case 'integer': // whatever
    case 'null': // etc
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`switch` uses equality, not identity](http://php.net/switch) ("Note that switch/case does [loose comparision](http://php.net/types.comparisons#types.comparisions-loose) [sic]."), so even the first part of your example doesn't work the way you would expect it to.

Consider the following:

```
<?php
function checknull( $var )
{
  switch( $var )
  {
    case null:
      echo '$var is null!';
      break;
  }
}

checknull(null);
checknull(0);
checknull(false);
checknull('');
checknull(array());
```

All of the calls to `checknull()` in the above code will result in the text "$var is null!" being output.

As noted in other answers, an `if...else` will probably serve your purposes better here.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do `case INTEGER`. NULL is a specific value, INTEGER is a data type.

You'd need to use an if statement with `is_int()`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to use a switch statement? What's wrong with a simple if/else block?

```
<?php
if ( is_numeric($action) ) {
    // $action is numeric; perform relevant actions
} else {
    // it's not numeric.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a string is a valid integer you could use [`ctype_digit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Comment: This works, but you have to cast the value to a string.  `ctype_digit(123)` returns `false`, whereas `ctype_digit((string)123)` returns `true`.