# Switch statement handles conditions different than if/else

Tags: php

I created a switch statement to handle three different cases and return a result. The switch statement always fired on the first case, despite it being false. When I created an if/else statement, it works as expected. Why is this? **(keep in mind that I do not use both the switch and if/else at the same time, I only have them both uncommented to show my example)**

Here is the function that I am working with:

```
public static function statuses($statusId = null)
{
    $statuses = [
        1 => 'Choose Vendor',
        2 => 'Approve Quote',
        3 => 'Waiting on Forecast',
        4 => 'Waiting on Sign Approval',
        5 => 'Waiting on Final Approval',
        6 => 'Waiting on Review',
        7 => 'Completed'
    ];

    // This works as expected...   
    if (is_numeric($statusId)) {
        return $statuses[$statusId];
    } elseif (is_string($statusId)) {
        return array_search($statusId, $statuses);
    } else {
        return $statuses;
    }

    // This does not work as expected
    switch ($statusId) {
        case is_numeric($statusId):
            // This always fires and the result is FALSE
            var_dump(is_numeric($statusId));
            return $statuses[$statusId];
        case is_string($statusId):
            return array_search($statusId, $statuses);
        default:
            return $statuses;
    }
}
```

And here is how I am calling the method:

```
SignVendorJob::statuses()
```

Which should return the array since I am not passing an argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can case is\_numeric($action): be written another way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950874/can-case-is-numericaction-be-written-another-way)

Comment: Perhaps because  it isn't an if/else statement.... effectively what you're doing is `if ($statusId == is_numeric($statusId)) {...} elseif ($statusId == is_string($statusId)) {...} else {...}` which is a nonsense

Comment: @dericcain You're right, I did. Though I deleted it seconds later :P

Comment: @MarkBaker You are completely right.. I was approaching the switch statement as if it were a if/else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statement should be like this:

```
switch (true) {
    case is_numeric($statusId):
        // This always fires and the result is FALSE
        var_dump(is_numeric($statusId));
        return $statuses[$statusId];
    case is_string($statusId):
        return array_search($statusId, $statuses);
    default:
        return $statuses;
}
```

Notice the change after `switch`.

In your example the following conditions are tested in the cases:

`$statusId == is_numeric($statusId)` and `$statusId == is_string($statusId)`
These will give wrong results.

Comment: Basically, it's a simple case of not using the switch statement correctly. I see that I am supposed to put what I'm testing against in the switch parameter and not the variable that I'm testing. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll mark it correct as soon as it allows me.